# How to avoid collisions using HashCode.Combine?

Tags: c#, hash, .net-core

I'm running into a collision building a hashtable with a fairly small data set (~100k rows). Am I doing something wrong here?

Here is an example of 2 bits of data that will usually generate the same hashes. (An occasional run will generate different hashes):

```
long long1 = 330765;
long long2 = 227691;
DateTime date1= new DateTime(2016, 5, 24);
DateTime date2= new DateTime(2016, 1, 25);

var c1 = HashCode.Combine(long1, date1);
var c2 = HashCode.Combine(long2, date2);
Console.WriteLine(c1);
Console.WriteLine(c2);
```

Reproducible with dotnetcore 2.1

Comment: What are you using for combine?  With has you have to be careful that "DataTable"  and "Data" + "Table" both give same hash.  To prevent duplication normally you would use "Data" + "^" + "Table" when you combine so you get two different hash values.

Comment: Collision on 100k items is expectable behavior.

Comment: This is the standard birthday problem. The probability of a collision with 100k items in a 32-bit space is 68%.

Comment: @MikeZboray With a perfect hash and random data.  So that's a best case of the odds.  It can go up from there if the data isn't random, or the hash is imperfect.

Comment: @Servy Yup I was going to add that. Combine isn't perfect and the input data probably doesn't cover the full key space, and of course a simple hash table doesn't have that many buckets.

Comment: @MikeZboray So a long is 64 bit, and datetime.ticks is 64 bits. Hashing those numbers into a 32 bit integer is not going to scale very far. That is surprising, but so is the birthday paradox. Thanks for explaining that guys.

Comment: @jdweng `HashCode.Combine` here probably refers to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode.combine?view=net-8.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can *never* avoid collisions entirely with hash codes (except for types that have less than 2^32 possible distinct values, like shorts or bytes or something like that).  Writing a good hash simply means minimizing your collisions as much as you can.  You can do this by doing your best to ensure that your hash codes are (approximately) evenly distributed across the entire range of `int`.

You can also try to avoid certain values commonly used together colliding (for example, you could come up with a generation algorithm for dates such that dates in the same week wouldn't collide, and ensuring all collisions were in dates further apart than that).

But any time you're using generated hash codes you need to have some mechanism for dealing with the collisions.

Comment: Could you give an example/url to a mechanism you can put in place to mitigate collisions?

Comment: To clarify, I meant for the third paragraph*.

Comment: Dealing with does not mean mitigate collisions. It means have some behaviour to handle the rare situations where they occur. Consider the Dictionary class. It uses the hashcode to compute the bucket, but then puts an array in the bucket rather than a single element. This means that collisions are dealt with by enumeration over that array until it finds it (or doesn't).

Comment: @Servy : Absolutely wrong!!!  The hash should only be a first level check that items are equal.  After the hash comparison, you always need to compare the objects to make sure which duplicate you are working with.  A comparison using a hash returns a List<object>.  So if you look at the msdn IEqualityComparer (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.7.2).  After the GetHashCode() is called the Equals() is called and in equal you must test the key matches to avoid the collisions.

Comment: @jdweng OK. Let's have a simple example. Consider a hash function for `bool`. It returns 0 for `false` and 1 for `true`. Please explain how a collision can occur.

Comment: David you know a bool does not cause a collision.  The IEquelityComarer uses a hash and never gets a collision while the hash by itself does get collisions.

Comment: @jdweng Where did I ever contradict that?  I *specifically* said that anytime you're using hash codes (and you are using a type that has less than 2^32 possible values) you need to have some mechanism for dealing with the hash collisions.

Comment: @Servy : Just reading your first paragraph by itself is what my issue is all about.  Then the second paragraph is wrong since you can never avoid the collision.  The third paragraph is vague not giving a real solution.  It would of been much better to reference the IEqualityComparer which is a solution.

Comment: @jdweng For certain types you *can* avoid literally any collisions.  It's rare for it to come up, but not impossible.  Additionally, even if you can't avoid collisions entirely for a type, you can avoid certain sub-groups of that type from colliding.  For example, you could do exactly what I proposed and write a hash code generator for `DateTime` that never collided for values within the same week.  Thus, if you knew a given hash-based collection always had items within the same week, they'd never collide (or, if your times were just generally close together, collisions would be rarer).

Comment: @jdweng Would you care to provide some sort of citation for your assertion that there are no types that can avoid collisions entirely (by having less than 2^32 possible values) or that you can't avoid collisions entirely within certain sub-groups of a type?  Additionally `IEqualityComparer` doesn't *solve* the problem of collisions, it simply provides an additional tool which various hash-based collections can use to handle collisions.

Comment: As I said : Never write code that occasionally gives errors when you can write code that works 100% of the time!!!

Comment: @jdweng 1) No, you didn't say that earlier 2) I never said that you should write code that occasionally gives errors.